# Getting error for youtubeplayerview. Can't embed youtube videos in android studio

Tags: android-studio, youtube-api

How to add a YouTube player to an Android app using the `com.pierfrancescosoffritti.androidyoutubeplayer` dependency?

MainActivity.java:

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private YouTubePlayerView youTubePlayerView;
    
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        
        youTubePlayerView = findViewById(R.id.youtubeplayerid);
        
        youTubePlayerView.addYouTubePlayerListener(new AbstractYouTubePlayerListener() {
            @Override
            public void onReady(@NonNull YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer) {
                String videoId = "fis26HvvDII";
                youTubePlayer.cueVideo(videoId, 0);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml:

```xml
<com.pierfrancescosoffritti.androidyoutubeplayer.core.player.views.YouTubePlayerView
        android:id="@+id/youtubeplayerid"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:ignore="MissingClass,MissingConstraints" />
```

build.gradle:

```groovy
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.youtubeactivity"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.9.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'

    implementation 'com.pierfrancescosoffritti.androidyoutubeplayer:core:12.0.0'
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: could not solve as youtubeplayerview api is paid now.used webview instead @AhmetYılmaz

Answer (score 0):

have you tried
app:autoPlay="false"

```
        android:id="@+id/youtube_player_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:autoPlay="false"
        />
```

and targetSdk 34